# Write Spark logs to STDOUT instead of STDERR

Tags: apache-spark, log4j

I have a service that reads the logs from STDOUT for further analysis. It seems like there has been struggle with writing spark logs to STDOUT, by default, log4j sends any kind of log to STDERR.

Is there a way to change this behavior?

What changes need to be made specifically to move logs from STDERR to STDOUT?

Here's what my log4j file looks like:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, FILE

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.FILE.File=stderr
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=....
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=5248997
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=10


log4j.logger.org.spark_project.jetty=WARN
log4j.logger.org.spark_project.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.parquet=ERROR
log4j.logger.parquet=ERROR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a spark submit add `2>&1` at the the end. This means combine stderr(2) and stdout(1) into the stdout stream.

To do it through log4j.properties file, try adding the below properties.

```
# Log everything INFO and above to stdout
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,console

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.console.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %-5p %.26c [%X{testName}] [%X{akkaSource}] - %m%n
```

Comment: Koedit, Meena:
I'm running this application using Java and referring to the log4j.properties by setting spark configuration from SparkConf(). What would be the SparkConf() equivalent operation of your suggestion?

Comment: can u pls share the command u are using to run the application.

Comment: Running this inside pod -> /docker-java-home/bin/java -cp /app/spark/conf/:/app/spark/jars/* -Xm****M -Dspark.driver.port=***** -Dlog4j.formatMsgNoLookups=true -Dlog4j.configuration=/app/spark/conf/log4.properties

Comment: In the log4j , try changing from file to console, have updated the properties above.

Comment: Have one more clarification, is your service reading the logs from a file?

Comment: Okay struck another problem! In the stderr file, I can see a comment in the beggining that says - Using default version of log4j. Does that mean that its unable to read my custom log4j.properties? I have changed all the possible files inside the pod with my properties, but still getting the msg. 
Regarding the service, yes its reading the logs from a file - more specifically stdout

Comment: Meena - Thank you, fixed the issue on my end and your solution seems to work perfectly